# Samsung A8 KG State prenormal

Tags: samsung, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018

I have problem with KG State prenormal on my Samsung Galaxy A8.

So, I installed TWRP, after I installed SaboorROM, and after connect to WiFi, the device set's the KG state to Prenormal and I was unable to boot into TWRP or into SaboorROM. So I installed Stock ROM (AP: A530FXXSBCTC4 | CSC: A530FODXBCTC2). After install I enabled Developer settings and OEM was already unlocked. So I tried to "date|time changing experiments" to reach KG state checking, but nothing worked. Than I was about 500 hours if KG state will change, nothing :/

OEM: unlocked 
FRP: unlock 
KG: prenormal
Binary: 11 Android: Pie

**How to change KG state?**

Comment: Same thing happened me as well. On my Galaxy A8 2018, I tried my different things such as changing ROMs, Custom ROMs, and may other things, but ended up triggering KG State Prenormal on my A8 2018, Now I can't use volte. So I using Jiocall.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not rebooting in a week there's another method that worked for my device (not galaxy a8) but i don't know if it will for you.

So, you need to:

- First flash (reflash) official stock firmware, i'd try to flash the version your device had when you bought it, but if you can't, try latest.
- Then boot and proceed with the setup. Skip connecting to the internet so you finish it faster.
- After you finished the setup, connect to the internet and wait. Enable OEM unlocking in developer settings if needed.
- Next log into any valid google account on your phone and wait some time (i waited about an hour).
- Reboot to odin mode and kg status should be checking.

If this doesn't work, try factory resetting after that (keeping the bootloader unlocked) and doing everything again but without even enabling developer options.

Answer (score 0):

[...] Sadly there is no workaround just yet. 1 week no reboot is useless if you are on Bootloader 7 (Android 10 or latest android 9 update)
https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-a6/help/official-released-binaries-allowed-to-t4102447
:(